# Some angular app working without ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-app

I have one [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18427/) of angularjs. This fiddle working fine but in HTML code `ng-app` is not defined. When I trying to create new fiddle of same code with same `angularjs` version then it is not working properly but in new fiddle if I add `ng-app` in top div then new created fiddle working fine.

Question: **Why** same code working for one fiddle which is not working for another new fiddle?

Update: In fiddle link `ng-app` is added by default but **why** it is added in fiddle without adding in HTML code

Comment: If you look in the console, and search for `ng-app`, you'll see it is automatically applied to `body`

Comment: I found that but I don't know why it is added by default without adding in code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside **Fiddle Options** you will find `<body ng-app="myApp">`

Comment: This is not `by default`. If you are going to create new fiddle, you will not find that. This is optional somebody use body tag to cleaner code and to focus problem specific code only.